# How to set icon for the desktop shortcut of setup project created using visual studio Installer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have created a `Setup Project` from `Visual Studio Installer`.
I installed the `MSI` and I was able to install the application. I want to add an icon for the shortcut I have created on the desktop. For this I tried the following steps:

> - **1)** Selected the desktop shortcut from the `FileSystem` view.
> - **2)** Press `F4` for properties.
> - **3)** For the **Icon** Field selected **Browse** option.
> - **4)** Clicked on **Browse** button.
> - **5)** Set `File of type` to Executable(.exe)
> - **6)** Press `OK` and `OK` again.
> - **7)** Then build my C# application and then the Setup Project.
> - **8)** Then ran the `MSI` from the debug location.
> - **9)** Then a shortcut created and as well as .exe file got installed on the desktop.
> - **10)** **ICON** size is `16*16`.

---

> The `.exe` file shows the **ICON** , where as the desktop shortcut for the same executable is not showing **ICON** and it showing as below.
> [image]

I can not figure out why it does not show the icon.

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 12):

Finally I resolved it. The solution for this is changing the ICON size from `16*16 to 48*48` pixel. I have set my application ICON size to `48*48 pixels` and the same is selected while setting the ICON for the desktop shortcut in the setup project.
Even ICON of size `24*24` also worked. Hope this helps someone looking for similar issue.

Comment: My setup project uses the 256*256 version for whatever reason, but this answer finally led me into the direction of "maybe the actual icon is the problem..." after struggling with this for WAY too long. +1

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem and i solved it when i included the *.ico file directly in the Installer Project.

First you have to include the *.ico file for your shortcut, rightclick on your installer project in solution explorer and "Add", then "File", then choose your icon. ( Settings.ico for example )

[image: Project Settings]

Then you should choose your icon file for the shortcut and click ok. ( your step 5 and 6 )

[image: Select Icon]

After installation, your icon should shown correct on the desktop.

Be aware that with this solution, the icon file is copied to your application folder after installation, but nobody should disturb that.

**EDIT:**

You should see your selected icon when you click on the right menu "(Icon)" => "(Browse...)":

[image: Show Icon]

Here the settings for the shortcut:

[image: Settings]

Check your settings if they fit.

Comment: As you suggested, I had added an .ico file to my setup project. Now selected "User's Desktop" created a shortcut and then from the properties I have selected application folder and "File of type" as "*.ico".Then rebuild the solution and then in the debug location there are exe and msi files. After running msi file it got installed and the shortcut created in the desktop. But still it does not show icon. In the program files  I found .ico file in the following location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dummy\SayHelloSetup". Could please help where am I doing wrong.

Comment: I've updated my post, check the settings if they help you.

Answer (score 0):

In MSVS->Setup go to "User's Programs Menu->Shortcut->Properties->Icon" select your Icon and rebuild.  This fixed it for me.